# "Missing start boundary" when sending Emails with Text attachment

Tags: actionmailer, amazon-ses

I have trouble sending Emails with text attachments (without attachment, everything is fine). I'm using actionmailer 3.2.11 and try to send Emails over Amazon SES. To me it looks like, that the amazon snmp server has a problem with the emails I produce. The code to produce the email looks like this:

```
class ServiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "noreply@dungeonpilot.com"


    def server_crashed log_file_names
        attachments[ 'foo.txt' ] = 'Hallo'
        mail to: 'Txxx@xxzki.de', subject: '[dungeonpilot] Server Crashed'
   end
end
```

The error message, when sending mails: `Net::SMTPFatalError: 554 Transaction failed: Missing start boundary`.

The resulting Mail is this:

```
Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2013 10:11:09 +0000
From: noreply@dungeonpilot.com
To: Txxx@xxxzki.de
Message-ID: <5114cf3dc4886_701165e7f848869@ip-10-62-103-46.mail>
Subject: [dungeonpilot] Server Crashed
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



--
Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2013 10:11:09 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=foo.txt
filename: foo.txt
Content-ID: <5114cf3d55085_701165e7f8487cc@ip-10-62-103-46.mail>

Hallo

----
```

Delivering this to SES as a Test Mail, results too in "Missing start boundary". So I think there must be something wrong with the delivered content.

In the views folder, there was just one .txt.erb template. I've added a .html.erb template and now there is a `boundary="`-header and boundaries between the mail parts:

```
Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2013 10:26:57 +0000
From: noreply@dungeonpilot.com
To: Torsten@Robitzki.de
Message-ID: <5114d2f1b8175_702812508041181@ip-10-62-103-46.mail>
Subject: [dungeonpilot] Server Crashed
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5114d2f18f621_7028125080411632";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



----==_mimepart_5114d2f18f621_7028125080411632
Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2013 10:26:57 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=foo.txt
filename: foo.txt
Content-ID: <5114d2f0ee34b_7028125080411545@ip-10-62-103-46.mail>

Hallo

----==_mimepart_5114d2f18f621_7028125080411632
Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2013 10:26:57 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <5114d2f19ce45_7028125080411785@ip-10-62-103-46.mail>



----==_mimepart_5114d2f18f621_7028125080411632--
```

Looks like a bug in ActionMailer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, I've named the template with a txt extension, not with a text extension.

The next version of actionmailer will throw an exception, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when the Email Text Body and Email HTML body were null.
So one of those has to have a value when sending emails using
Amazon Simple Email SendRawEmailAsync method

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. For me the attachment was getting attached properly. The solution that worked out for me was creating a view (server_crashed.html.erb).
After this when I ran the rake task, it worked fine and I was able to send mailer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, in my case I as appending an empty multipart in email body.